# Biztalk orchestration and AS2 synchronous MDN

Tags: biztalk

I am trying to send a synchronous MDN via AS2 and also bind that port to an orchestration. Is that possible? I tried the following link with no luck:
http://giancode1.blogspot.com/2014/08/as2-synchronous-mdn-with-orchestration.html

Update:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what issue / errors you are getting?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf there is no error that I am getting. A two-way (solicit-response) send port is needed for the Sync MDN; however, that port needs to be bound in the orchestration. If I do that; I have to bind a message to the response; and if I put an empty string I get:Failed while attempting to send message 'MDNMessage'.
        
Exception type: SendFailedException (probably because the MDN was already sent). With this solution the MDN is send back; but the orchestration fails.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the port to the Orchestration, you can always put a filter expression in the Receive Shape of the Orchestration, and you can make it a one way Logical Port in the Orchestration, so you don't send out two responses.

Comment: thank you for your response, sounds promising! I added the Orchestration to the question. Could you look into it and explain in more details how the filter should look like? Right now it's a one way receive port bound; I guess we have to change that to a two way.

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei Is the Orchestration the only thing that is responding to the solicit-response or is there something else as well?  Your question is a bit confused on that point.  If it is Only the Orchestration, then all you need to do is have a two way logical port.